# SQL : Oracle : Optimize LEFT Outer Join Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 1 local table (all column names different from remote tables except one)  and 2 remote tables (which have same column names) for which I need to combine the data.

Following is the query I have written using LEFT OUTER JOIN and UNION but the performance is slow.

Could anyone please help optimize this query?

```
select
"CONTROL_M_SERVER",
"HOST",
CASE
WHEN "AGSTAT" = 'V' THEN 'Available'
WHEN "AGSTAT" = 'U' THEN 'Unavailable'
WHEN "AGSTAT" = 'R' THEN 'Discovering'
ELSE 'Not Defined in Control-M'
END as Agent_Status,
T1.VERSION,
"PORTS",
"MANAGEMENT_IP",
"OPERATING_SYSTEM",
"CLUSTER_ALIAS",
"NODEGROUP",
"APPLICATION_ID",
"DATE_CONFIGURED",
"CONFIGURED_BY"
from "CTMAGENTAUDIT" T1
left outer join (select NODEID,AGSTAT from CMR_NODES@SPDB UNION ALL select NODEID,AGSTAT from CMR_NODES@DEVDB) T2 on T2.NODEID = T1.HOST;
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major issue I see with your query is the outermost left join between `CTMAGENTAUDIT` and the subquery which contains the union.  The problem with that subquery is that, as written, Oracle can't possibly use any index for the join.  This means that Oracle will probably have to resort to a slower method when joining, possibly a full scan.

One approach here would be to create a materialized view containing the union query, and then index it:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW T2 AS
SELECT NODEID, AGSTAT FROM CMR_NODES@SPDB
UNION ALL
SELECT NODEID, AGSTAT FROM CMR_NODES@DEVDB;

CREATE INDEX mv_node_idx ON T2 (NODEID);
```

With this indexed materialized view in place, I would expect your query to perform much better now:

```
SELECT
    CONTROL_M_SERVER,
    HOST,
    CASE WHEN AGSTAT = 'V' THEN 'Available'
         WHEN AGSTAT = 'U' THEN 'Unavailable'
         WHEN AGSTAT = 'R' THEN 'Discovering'
         ELSE 'Not Defined in Control-M' END AS Agent_Status,
    T1.VERSION,
    PORTS,
    MANAGEMENT_IP,
    OPERATING_SYSTEM,
    CLUSTER_ALIAS,
    NODEGROUP,
    APPLICATION_ID,
    DATE_CONFIGURED,
    CONFIGURED_BY
FROM CTMAGENTAUDIT T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
    ON T2.NODEID = T1.HOST;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the prompt response. I’ll test this out and let you know how it goes. Am I right in assuming that the materialized view is to be created on the local database to which I have full rights. The remote DBS are application ones which I don’t have full admin rights.

Comment: @venky_au I guess you would have to create the view where you have the rights/ability to do so.

Comment: This worked very well for my requirement. Thanks a lot for your expert advice. Lastly, are their any recurring admin/maintenance tasks involved with materialized views that I need to scope in.

Comment: Yes, you might have to refresh and reindex the view if the underlying data in the two tables changes.  But, would this be a problem for you?  When I answered I sort of imagined that this was a one time reporting requirement.

Comment: Hi Tim no this is an ongoing report. And no refreshing shouldn’t be a problem. Could you please give me some hints on how to setup that refresh. We should be fine if the refresh is to happen only once or twice a day

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
select
"CONTROL_M_SERVER",
"HOST",
CASE
WHEN "AGSTAT" = 'V' THEN 'Available'
WHEN "AGSTAT" = 'U' THEN 'Unavailable'
WHEN "AGSTAT" = 'R' THEN 'Discovering'
ELSE 'Not Defined in Control-M'
END as Agent_Status,
T1.VERSION,
"PORTS",
"MANAGEMENT_IP",
"OPERATING_SYSTEM",
"CLUSTER_ALIAS",
"NODEGROUP",
"APPLICATION_ID",
"DATE_CONFIGURED",
"CONFIGURED_BY",
(select t2.NODEID, t2.AGSTAT from CMR_NODES@SPDB t2 where t1.host = t2.nodeid),  
(select t3.NODEID, t3.AGSTAT from CMR_NODES@DEVDB t3 where T1.HOST = T3.NODEID) from t1;
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for your prompt response. I’ll test this out and let you know how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically:

```
select . . .
from CTMAGENTAUDIT T1 left outer join
     (select NODEID, AGSTAT
      from CMR_NODES@SPDB UNION ALL
      select NODEID, AGSTAT
      from CMR_NODES@DEVDB
     ) T2
     on T2.NODEID = T1.HOST;
```

Assuming `NODEID`/`AGSTAT` combos are unique in each of the `CMR_NODE` tables, I would write this as:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(s1.AGSTAT, s2.AGSTAT) as AGSTAT,
       (case coalesce(s1.AGSTAT, s2.AGSTAT) 
            when 'V' then 'Available'
            when 'U' then 'Unavailable'
            when 'R' then 'Discovering'
            else 'Not Defined in Control-M'
        end) as Agent_Status
from CTMAGENTAUDIT T1 left outer join
     CMR_NODES@SPDB s1
     on s1.NODEID = T1.HOST left outer join
     CMR_NODES@DEVDB s2
     on s1.NODEID = T1.HOST
```

This will at least allow each table to be optimized separately -- which should help.

Obviously, the solution with the materialized view will be faster, if you have the permissions and desire to set up cross-server materialized views.  There are additional maintenance issues with materialized views, particularly if you have multiple such views and assume that they are updated at the same time.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your prompt response. I’ll test this out and let you know how this goes.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked like a charm. Thanks. Only one issue though, if you see my original query I am printing the AGSTAT using CASE statement. How do I do that with coalesce ?